# facebook group add to site

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init();

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
            runFbInitCriticalCode(); 
            console.log(response);
        });

        (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js#xfbml=1";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    };
});
```

html:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

i don't see any errors, but I can't show a group window, what I am doing wrong? as I've learned, all the params to the FB.INIT are optional, but how to see the error installing AND executing FB scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS is wrong. You're trying to include the Facebook JS inside of the facebook ready callback.

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init();

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
            runFbInitCriticalCode(); 
            console.log(response);
        });
    }

    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

});
```